# YouTube Video Editor With Titles

Tags: gratis, video-editing

I want to create videos for YouTube and in doing so I need a video editor software.

The software needs to have:

- Animated title templates for the introduction.
- Captioning with different fonts and colours.
- A GUI
- A timeline (preferably)
- Low hardware processing requirements

I have used Davinci Resolve 16 and OpenShot. They do not suit my needs as Resolve requires a lot of hardware power and OpenShot indirectly requires a graphics card I do not have.

It also needs to be free with no watermark. Is there a software which applies to all of these?

Comment: Video editing normally requires a lot of hardware power, or a lot of time to compensate for it.

Comment: @Alejandro I don't need hardcore editing software. I just need the captioning and animated titles. So a fully fledged package is not needed. There won't be any heavy colour grading or VFX, like with many editors.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest taking a look at [MoviePy](https://zulko.github.io/moviepy/) which of course requires [Python](https://www.python.org/) as a pre-requisite and for captioning [ImageMagick](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php). Behind the scenes MoviePy relies on FFMPEG but *it installs its own copy for you on first use*.

What it doesn't give you is a GUI but of course that does mean that it is much lighter on its hardware requirements.
It can give you:

- Animated titles (even [Star Wars Like](https://youtu.be/5euLdo8L0o0) or [partially hidden](https://youtu.be/NsTgBah6Ebk))
  [image][image]
- The use of scripts, *(rather than templates),* to preform work that you regularly do
- Captions in different colours & fonts
- Much more

And everything mentioned is Free and will work on multiple platforms from a Raspberry Pi to a super computer.

Comment: Thank you, but my requirements have changed recently, as you can see in the post. Moviepy needs me to enter the commands into a terminal, and that isn't ideal.